# Can't connect to Sql Server database using JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

I'm trying to make a connection to an already existing database in SQL Server 2012n with Netbeans 8.

Using the connection wizard I select Sql Server 2012 and enter the credentials and fields.

However I get the message that a connection cannot be established.

You can see screenshots of the entered fields:

[image: Sql Server]

[image: Netbeans connection wizard]

I also tried using "localhost" instead of "STIJN" this didn't work. I also tried with the default port "1433". Also didn't worked, however what port should this be? Where can I see what port I'm using? Maybe the error lies in the port, otherwise I wouldn't know where I made a mistake.

Comment: Are you sure that the server is actually listening on a TCP-IP port instead of just named pipes?

Comment: How do I check this? First time I'm doing this so complete noob on this

Comment: you can use nmap to test if sqlserver is running on a specific port by using this command `nmap -p port_number ip`

Comment: Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-03-28 13:10 Romance (standaardtijd)

Skipping SYN Stealth Scan against localhost (127.0.0.1) because Windows does not support scanning your own machine (localhost) this way.

Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)

Host is up.

PORT     STATE   SERVICE

1433/tcp unknown ms-sql-s



Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.96 seconds

Comment: I think you should add port number to your connection string

Comment: Already tried with and without it, no success

Comment: this is my url now: jdbc:sqlserver://STIJN\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=HOGENT1415_11

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Go to your SQL Server configuration manager -> SQL server network configuration -> protocols for SQLEXPRESS -> TCP/IP (double click on it for properties).

On protocol page set enabled to Yes.
On IP Addresses page, scroll to bottom.
TCP Dynamic Ports: 54629
TCP Port: 1433
Apply and ok.

Make a connection with:
Host: localhost
Port: 1433
Your credentials
Instance field = blank.

This should work.